# update and return in GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want to update a record while returning a field from the record. If I don't return in the same command there might be concurrency issues that is why I want it to be an atomic operation. Can somebody guide me as to how to achieve this in Gorm?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `func (*DB) BeginTx` to start a transaction and when you are done with calculation or updates, you can use `func (s *DB) Commit() *DB` to update transaction. It will lock the table to ensure atomic operation(In case of error use Rollback).

For more Information of this function use this link:
https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.BeginTx

For example(Sample Golang Code):

```
    db, err := mysql.SharedStore().BeginTx()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer func() { _ = db.Rollback() }()
    //calculations
    db.CommitTx()
```